# Custom message based on Total for Free delivery

Tags: magento-1, custom, popup, delivery

Is it possible to display a message in a pop-up box or alert on the cart page when a customer is close to the free delivery threshold i.e.

> "Spend another £5 and you qualify for free delivery"

Comment: You could probably set up an observer on `catalog_product_load_after` like is suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763829/magento-load-product-event-observer). You would have to get the cart total and compare it to your free delivery threshold, but it shouldn't be too hard to set up. You can get the cart totals with something like `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getGrandTotal()`

Comment: @travisw. Why the event `catalog_product_load_after`? Also you should not use `getGrandTotal`. The free shipping conditions are based on `getSubtotal`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your own module. Let's call it `StackExchange_FreeShipping`
you will need the following files:

`app/etc/modules/StackExchange_FreeShipping.xml` - the declaration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <StackExchange_FreeShipping>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Shipping />
            </depends>
        </StackExchange_FreeShipping>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/StackExchange/FreeShipping/etc/config.xml` - the configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <StackExchange_FreeShipping>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </StackExchange_FreeShipping>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <stackexchange_freeshipping>
                <class>StackExchange_FreeShipping_Helper</class>
            </stackexchange_freeshipping>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <stackexchange_freeshipping>
                <class>StackExchange_FreeShipping_Model</class>
            </stackexchange_freeshipping>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <StackExchange_FreeShipping>
                    <files>
                        <default>StackExchange_FreeShipping.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </StackExchange_FreeShipping>
            </modules>
        </translate>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index>
                <observers>
                    <stackexchange_freeshipping>
                        <class>stackexchange_freeshipping/observer</class>
                        <method>checkFreeShipping</method>
                    </stackexchange_freeshipping>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/StackExchange/FreeShipping/Model/Observer.php` - the observer that checks if you are close to free shipping

```
<?php
class StackExchange_FreeShipping_Model_Observer 
{
    public function checkFreeShipping($observer) 
    {
        //if free shipping is not enabled, do nothing
        if (!Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/freeshipping/active')) {
            return $this;
        }
        $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        //if there are no products in the cart, again, do nothing
        if (count($quote->getAllItems()) == 0 ){
            return $this;
        }
        //get the quote subtotal
        $subtotal = $quote->getSubtotal();
        //get the free shipping
        $freeShippingValue = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/freeshipping/free_shipping_subtotal');
        //check if the cart is below the free shipping amount
        if ($freeShippingValue > $subtotal) {
            Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addNotice(
                Mage::helper('stackexchange_freeshipping')->__(
                    'Your cart has the has the value of %s. In order to get free shipping you need to order for %s more',
                    '<span style="color:green">'.Mage::helper('core')->currency($subtotal, true, false).'</span>',
                    '<span style="color:red">'.Mage::helper('core')->currency($freeShippingValue - $subtotal, true, false).'</span>'
                )
            );
        }

    }
}
```

`app/locale/en_US/StackExchange_FreeShipping.csv` - the translation file. You can add this for every language you have:

```
"Your cart has the has the value of %s. In order to get free shipping you need to order for %s more","Your cart has the has the value of %s. In order to get free shipping you need to order for %s more"
```

Of course change the text if you want it different.
Clean the cache and give it a go.
You should see now in the cart a notice message above the cart table with the message

```
Your cart has the has the value of 34$. In order to get free shipping you need to order for 15$ more.
```

Comment: Thanks for this @Marius. I've implement your suggestion but I am getting a white screen. I've checked the event log nothing in there.

Comment: Try to debug step by step. I haven't tested the  code. I just addapted it from an extension i built a long time ago. It might have syntax errors.

Comment: I got it working. I forgot to create the helper.

Answer (score 0):

On completing the answer of @Marius, you have to add else the helper, otherwise you will have an error without

**app/code/local/StackExchange/FreeShipping/Helper/Data.php**

```
<?php
class StackExchange_FreeShipping_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{

}
```

Comment: Works great for me! Only thing I'd like to add (@Prince) is to clarify the information on the "helper" step, for those that aren't soaring with the eagles (like me). The "helper" file name that he forgot to add is Data.php.
As in: `app/code/local/StackExchange/FreeShipping/Helper/Data.php` His helper code works fine.