# How to Create Helper Data?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, magento-1, helper

I recently find the custom message based on the total for free delivery [Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75909/custom-message-based-on-total-for-free-delivery). I create the module as said @Marius but, I am the new one to Magento so I am unable to create Hepler Data.

I don't Have 50reputations for comment on the page so I am raising my question Here:

How to Create Helper_Data for the module?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

go to `app/code/local/StackExchange/FreeShipping/Helper` folder and create a file with the name of `Data.php` and write below code

```
<?php
class StackExchange_FreeShipping_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can directly create default `Helper` class in the below location:

`app/code/local/StackExchange/FreeShipping/Helper/Data.php`

With below code:

```
class StackExchange_FreeShipping_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In your module `app/code/local/StackExchange/FreeShipping/etc/config.xml`, within the `<global>` tags

```
<helpers>
  <stackexchange_freeshipping>
      <class>StackExchange_FreeShipping_Helper</class>
  </stackexchange_freeshipping>
</helpers>
```

Then create the file `app/code/local/StackExchange/FreeShipping/Helper/Data.php`

```
<?php

class StackExchange_FreeShipping_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{

}
```

Then to call that module, you would use

```
$helper = Mage::helper('stackexchange_freeshipping');
```