# How to show popup?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, custom, popup, delivery

I am using [Custom Message Based on Total for free Delivery](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75909/custom-message-based-on-total-for-free-delivery) Module on my site, but it's showing , its only showing on checkout/cart page.

"How can I show module instead of the only checkout page to all the pages when adding the product to cart?"

Is it possible to show a popup for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `config.xml` file change below line

instead of

```
<controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index>
```

replace with

```
<controller_action_predispatch>
```

change closing tags as well

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer!! But it's not working on my [site](http://rajivpastula.com/magento/) Please check my site and update me.

Comment: @Rajiv after add to cart this message showing in all page just visit the page, I am teting your site and message showing me in all page after add to cart, clear your browser cache and visit site again

Comment: Yes, It is working. But still, it's not showing on MainPage(index.php)

Answer (score 0):

Following the tutorial that you used, the message is displayed when the event triggers `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_index` thats why its showing only in `checkout/cart` page, to display it in the other pages, it will be necessary to add the other events appropriate to these pages in your `config.xml` in `events` tag as you did for `checkout/cart`

```
<events>
   <controller_action_predispatch>
        <observers>
            <stackexchange_freeshipping>
                <class>stackexchange_freeshipping/observer</class>
                <method>checkFreeShipping</method>
            </stackexchange_freeshipping>
        </observers>
   </controller_action_predispatch>
</events>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am new to Magento please explain step by step that will help me most.

Comment: Like the answer of @Murtuza Zabuawala `<controller_action_predispatch>`