# How to Get Custom Message Based on Total for free Delivery like Jet.com?

Tags: magento-1.9, css, custom, popup, delivery

I am using [Custom Message Based on Total for free Delivery](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/75909/custom-message-based-on-total-for-free-delivery), It is working very good but I need appearance should be like jet.com

FYI: [Video](https://app.hyfy.io/v/abefbd5ZR6U/) and Image

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: this is completely based on your theme structure

Comment: at least can I get pop instead of right sidebar?

Comment: share your website url so I can try and tell you something

Comment: my dev site [link](https://www.rajivpastula.com/pataakdemo/) and please [email](pastularavji@gmail.com) me for FTP login details if needed!! Thanks very much for being you support on every time!!